# CSS Positioning: Why doesn't the width attribute work for these divs?

Tags: css, html, width

I am developing a new HTML/CSS screen. I two fields:

- Personal Cell
- Personal Email

Both are controlled by the same CSS class( eci_text), both are in a div.   Putting in width values for that class seems to have no effect on the div.   Why is that and what can I do about it?   I would like the the text fields next to each of the 2 strings above to line up vertically ( that is why I want to adjust the width of the eci_text divs )

Thanks much in advance

Steve

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Acme Emergency Page</title>
    <style TYPE="text/css">
        body 
        {
            background-color:white;
        }
        #container
        {
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            text-align:center;
            width: 99%;
            font-family:Arial,Helvetica;
            font-size:10pt;
        }
        #eci_container
        {
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            width:500px;
            text-align:center;
        }
        .paragrah_left
        {
            text-align:left;
        }
        .eci_textfield_container
        {
            text-align:left;
        }
        .eci_text
        {
            text-align:left;
            display:inline;
            width:150px;
        }
        .eci_textfield
        {
            text-align:left;
            display:inline;
        }
        .eci_checkbox
        {
            margin-left:40px;
            text-align:left;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>


 <div id="container">
     <!-- Content: Start div content: Main content area -->
     <div id="content">
     <h2>ACME Emergency Contact Information </h2>




<!-- Start: ECI Container -->
<div id = "eci_container">

    <p class = "paragrah_left">
        This voluntary information will only be used by the ACME Emergency 
        Fruit & Vegetable System (FAV) to tell you about emergencies when they 
        arise, whether you are at work or not.
    </p>

    <div class = "eci_textfield_container">
        <div class = "eci_text">        
            Personal Cell*: 
        </div>
        <div class = "eci_textfield">  
            <input type = "text" name= "personal_cell_phone_number">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "eci_checkbox">
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "checkBoxVisiblePersonalCellPhoneNumber">
        Make my personal cell phone number visible to Mark Zuckerberg's staff
    </div>

    <div class = "eci_checkbox">
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "checkBoxUsePersonalCellPhoneNumberForAlerts">
        Use this number for ENS SMS text alerts
    </div>

    <p class = "paragrah_left">
        If you do not want your personal cell phone used, please call
    </p>

    <div class = "eci_textfield_container">
        <div class = "eci_text">
            Personal Email*:
        </div>
        <div class = "eci_textfield">  
            <input type = "text" name= "personal_email">
        </div>
    </div>

    <p class = "paragrah_left">
        If you do not want your personal email used please call
    </p>






<!-- End: ECI Container -->
</div>
<!-- Content: Close div id ="content"  -->
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which divs is the problem with?

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if we didn't have to look at your entire form to troubleshoot the problem.  Can you remove the extra markup and CSS - such as the paragraphs, containers and check boxes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried display:block, and floating left?

Comment: It worked.  Why?  Why did dispaying the divs using eci_text as inline shut off the ability to change the width?

Comment: The width of inline is determined on the content of that div I believe. If you had another div inside, and set the width of that it would work. I stick with using display:block.

Answer (score 2):

Use a list and labels instead of DIVs. DIVs mean nothing. Lists and labels are a good part of using semantic HTML.

See: http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=406

```
<form action="#" class="myform">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Leave a Comment</legend>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input id="name" />
            </li>
        </ul>
```

... etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
        .eci_textfield_container
    {
        text-align:left;
        float:left;
        width:100%;
    }
    .eci_text
    {
        text-align:left;
        display:block;
        width:150px;
        float:left;
    }

    .eci_textfield
    {
        text-align:left;
        display:block;
        float:left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The width is being applied to both divs that encompass the field labels. If you use the Firebug extension in Firefox, you can inspect the element and see that the label is the width (150px) that you specified in your CSS. What browser are you actually seeing this issue in?

Also, for field labels, you should be using the  tag.

Comment: Yes, those results are my intent.  I would like to expand the width of the divs using class eci_text to be greater than 150px, but changing the numbers seems to have no effect.

Comment: The width isn't changing because you're switching from the default display for a div from block to inline. I'd remove the display: inline and float the divs left. You'll possibly need to clear your floats. I'd recommend using the clearfix CSS solution. http://themergency.com/css-clearfix-demystified/